# Capture data from FORM using jQuery/Ajax/JSON

Tags: asp.net, json, jquery

I have a few textboxes on a form and when the user submits I want to capture the data and insert it into a database.

Here is what my code looks like

```
// Called just before the form is submitted.
beforeSubmit: function(data)
{
    var item = $("[id$='item']");
    var category = $("[id$='category']");
    var record = $("[id$='record']");

    var json = "{'ItemName':'" + escape(item.val()) +
        "','CategoryID':'" + category.val() + "','RecordID':'" + record.val() + "'}";

    //This page is where data is to be retrieved and processed.
    var ajaxPage = "DataProcessor.aspx?Save=1";

    var options =
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxPage,
        data: json,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function(response)
        {
            alert("success: " + response);
        },
        error: function(msg)
        {
            alert("failed: " + msg);
        }
    };

    //Execute the Ajax call and get a response.
    var returnText = $.ajax(options).responseText;
    if (returnText == 1) {
        record.html(returnText);
        $("#divMsg").html("<font color=blue>Record saved successfully.</font>");
    }
    else
    {
        record.html(returnText);
        $("#divMsg").html("<font color=red>Record not saved successfully.</font>");
    }

    // $("#data").html("<font color=blue>Data sent to the server :</font> <br />" + $.param(data));
},
```

Here is what data is sent to the server: if I uncomment the following line.

```
 // $("#data").html("<font color=blue>Data sent to the server :</font> <br />" + $.param(data));
```

```
__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwULLTE4ODM1ODM4NDFkZOFEQfA7cHuTisEwOQmIaj1nYR23&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWDwLuksaHBgLniKOABAKV8o75BgLlosbxAgKUjpHvCALf9YLVCgLCtfnhAQKyqcC9BQL357nNAQLW9%2FeuDQKvpuq2CALyveCRDwKgoPWXDAKhwImNCwKiwImN &day_fi=12&month_fi=12&year_fi=1234&lastFour_fi=777&countryPrefix_fi=1&areaCode_fi=555-555&phoneNumber_fi=5555&email_fi=nisardotnet%40gmail.com&username=nisarkhan&password=123456&retypePassword=123456
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nisardotnet - are you working in C#? You've got way too much going on here. You can cut down your code by half using web methods - also, get rid of viewstate - you don't need it (remove the form from the page)

If your working in C# let me know and I can help.
Rob

****APPEND****

Ok - I built a simple "grab input values and update DB" thing - it's on my site [here](http://sites.google.com/site/fernandothecodemonkey/formless-sql-server-update-using-html-jquery-asp-net-c-and-sql-server).

Give me a shout if you've got any questions.
Rob

****APPEND****

Ok, so in your class file you could have

```
internal static void updateDB(String values)
{
    // do something with 'values'
}
```

Then in your aspx page you can call it like so...

```
[WebMethod]
public static void updateDB(String values)
{
    yourClass.updateDB(values);
}
```

That should work.

Comment: Rob, i have tested your solution and it wokks but when i try to put the webmethod in the class then it fails. have you tried put the updateDb in class and see?

here is the error message:

HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden. 

 var url = "App_Code/WebMethods.cs/updateDB";
or
 var url = "WebMethods.cs/updateDB";

Comment: Abu - you cannot call the web method directly from the class file. It is, literally, forbidden! You can only make a call from jQuery.ajax to an aspx page (or asmx, but it's very buggy). So, you can put the method in a class file, but then you'll need another web method on your aspx page (or it's code behind) that you call from jQuery.ajax. Does that make sense? - i've put some more explanation above

Comment: You're welcome. Hope it works for you. Once I figured this out, things got a lot easier and all my apps are now using it!

Take care

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pull it all out of the Request.Form.